# Activity codes filtering

Tags: c#, sql, filter, filtering

there is something called activity codes or task codes in the projects management softwares , like primavera p6 , ms project and synchro.
And for people who dont know what does activity codes mean , its like you give each task multiple value so you can filter the tasks using one code or more , and the user can make as many code as he need , so lets say each record has multiple code and it will be in the result if i called one of those codes.
For me , i thought of using assignment table between the tasks table and the codes table or using ALTER statment to add new column (new code) to the tasks table, but the problem in the number of the combo boxes that i need to choose the codes value in the form , so any one have better idea for that? Iam using c# for that purpose

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Generally you wouldn't alter tables to achieve a runtime data storage requirement. In this case you'd just have a table that has two columns; a project id and activity code. A project with 10 codes hs 10 rows in the table. A project with 57 activity codes has 57 rows in the table

Comment: yes i have mentioned that with assignment table , but the problem is how can i let the end-user to call ten codes for example ? i dont think its good idea to make combo box for each code